# How listener will be executed for objects hidden by another objects in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, flash-cs3, movieclip

I have two movie-clips, 
one is small-box and another is big-box .Both are rectangular shape. Small- box has an index 0, and big-box has an index 1. Their x,y are same and big-box being big in size gets hide small-box. Now the problem is the listener attached to small-box does not fire as big-box is on the top of small-box. what would be the way to get listener fired when click on small-box area??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `mouseEnabled = false` on the clip covering your button to make clicks go trough to objects below. If your boxes have children of their own, you may also need to set `mouseChildren = false`.